# Get next n business days using Oracle schdule

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

I am trying to find out the next working day exclude SAT, SUN and Holidays. I am getting the wrong output as follows.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION FUNC_TO_GET_NEXT_BUSINESS_DAY( 
P_DATE IN DATE 
,P_ADD_NUM IN INTEGER 
) RETURN DATE AS 
-- 
V_CNT NUMBER; 
V_BUS_DAY DATE := TRUNC(P_DATE); 
-- 
BEGIN 
-- 
SELECT MAX(RNUM) 
INTO V_CNT 
FROM (SELECT ROWNUM RNUM 
FROM ALL_OBJECTS) 
WHERE ROWNUM <= P_ADD_NUM 
AND TO_CHAR(V_BUS_DAY + RNUM, 'DY' ) NOT IN ('SAT', 'SUN') 
AND NOT EXISTS 
( SELECT 1 
FROM HOLIDAY_LIST 
WHERE HDLY_DATE = V_BUS_DAY + RNUM ); 
V_BUS_DAY := V_BUS_DAY + V_CNT; 
-- 
RETURN V_BUS_DAY; 
EXCEPTION 
  WHEN OTHERS THEN 
             Raise_application_error(-20010, SQLERRM); 
-- 
END FUNC_TO_GET_NEXT_BUSINESS_DAY; 
/
```

INPUT:

```
select FUNC_TO_GET_NEXT_BUSINESS_DAY(sysdate,1)+15/24 from dual;
```

Output:

```
3/23/2076 3:00:00 PM
```

Comment: I just compiled the function and tested with a few dates, and it is producing the correct output. Not sure why you get a date in 2076... take a look at your `HOLIDAY_LIST` to make sure it's correct. Also, I see you named a column HDLY_DATE - shouldn't that be HLDY_DATE?

Comment: There is almost never a reason to add an Exception block with something like WHEN OTHERS THEN. Just allow whatever exceptions the runtime throws be raised through the internal mechanism.

Answer (score 0):

I would do it like this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION FUNC_TO_GET_NEXT_BUSINESS_DAY(
    P_DATE IN DATE, 
    P_ADD_NUM IN INTEGER) 
RETURN DATE AS 

    TYPE Date_list IS TABLE OF DATE;
    Holidays Date_list;
    res DATE := TRUNC(P_DATE) + P_ADD_NUM;

BEGIN

    SELECT HDLY_DATE 
    BULK COLLECT INTO Holidays
    WHERE HDLY_DATE >= res
    FROM HOLIDAY_LIST; 

    LOOP
        EXIT WHEN res NOT MEMBER OF Holidays AND TO_CHAR(res, 'DY', 'NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE = american') NOT IN ('SAT', 'SUN'); 
        res := res + 1;
    END LOOP;   
    RETURN res;
end;
```

Comment: I am getting error when I use the above function in "BULK COLLECT".

Comment: The logic doesn't seem right. Say you want to add 10 days. Your function adds 10 days to today, and accepts that as the answer if it's not a weekend or a holiday. From the OP's explanation and his code, it seems he wants 10 **business** days forward, counting from today, which is a different concept.

Comment: @mathguy, yes most likely, I did not study his code in detail. It is not stated in the question.

Comment: I thought "Get next n **business** days" in the title suggested that.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I would write this, using mostly PL/SQL (minimizing context switches between PL/SQL and SQL). As in Wernfried's solution, I only need to read the HOLIDAY_LIST table into a PL/SQL table, then everything is processed in PL/SQL. Unlike Wernfried's solution, this version calculates the date that is a specified number of **business** days in the future, counting from the input date.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION FUNC_TO_GET_NEXT_BUSINESS_DAY ( 
  P_DATE    IN DATE   ,
  P_ADD_NUM IN INTEGER 
) RETURN DATE AS
  v_bus_day    date    := trunc(P_DATE);
  cnt          integer := P_ADD_NUM;
  type         date_list is table of date;
  holidays     date_list;
begin
  select  hdly_date
    bulk  collect into holidays
    from  holiday_list
    where hdly_date > v_bus_day;
  while cnt > 0
  loop
    v_bus_day := v_bus_day + 1;
    if   to_char(v_bus_day, 'DY') not in ('SAT', 'SUN')
      and
         v_bus_day not member of holidays
    then cnt := cnt - 1;
    end  if;
  end loop;
  return v_bus_day;
end;
/
```

Comment: You should make `TO_CHAR(v_bus_day, 'DY', 'NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE = american') NOT IN ('SAT', 'SUN')` in order to be independent from current user session NLS-Settings.

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit - right, but then we would also have to consider the definition of "weekend" (it's not Sat-Sun in all countries), etc. I generally try not to be "more Catholic than the Pope" (that the OP in these instances). The point is well taken though, of course.